# Почему лес называют дремучим?

Tags: значение-слов, однокоренные-слова

*"Мы не хотим развлекать себя прогулкой в "лесу символов", потому что у нас есть более девственный, более дремучий лес - божественная физиология, бесконечная сложность нашего тёмного организма.

О. Мандельштам, "Утро акмеизма"*

Так вот, почему лес называют дремучим? Ведь, насколько я понимаю, "дремучий" и "дрема", "дремать" - родственные слова. Но "дремучий лес" - это вовсе не сонный, а густой, непроходимый, дикий.
Какая связь?

Comment: Вопрос уже обсуждался http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/21917/однокоренные-слова-дремучий-и-дремота

Comment: @august, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: На санскрите созвучное с "дрема" слово вроде бы как раз имеет значение "лес"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дремучий лес  - это лес неизведанный, густой, темный, непроницаемый, заросший, труднопроходимый: верхушки деревьев переплетаются, ветер не шумит, птицы не летают, звери не бегают.

Отсутствие жизни, движения, света воспринимается нами как спящее, дремлющее, глухое, никак не проявляющее себя  пространство.

Answer (score 0):

Видимо, слова "дремучий", "дрема" произошли от английского "dream" - мечты, грёзы, видения... Дремучий означает сказочный.

Comment: Наоборот, "dream" от "дрёма".